# input-group keeps on expanding to the full width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to stop an input-group, the search box, from expanding to its full width:

[image: bootstrap]

At the moment the input-group is inside a span so that I can hide it when the page gets smaller, if I add it to a div, then I can manage to make it smaller with an inline style defining the width, but it remains on its own line instead of all being in one line.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="btn-group br">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success create-seller">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
                Create Seller
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="caret"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#seller-create" target="_blank">Create Seller In New Window</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group br">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary update-existing update-seller">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-save"></span>
                Save Seller
            </button>
        </div>

        <span class="visible-lg-inline">
            <div class="btn-group br">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary goto-first">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-backward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary goto-prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-backward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary clear-search">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary goto-next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-step-forward"></span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary goto-last">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fast-forward"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </span>
        <span class="visible-lg-inline">
            <div class="input-group br">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary qr-code">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <input class="form-control search top" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary search top dropdown-toggle" type="button"
                                data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            Search
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a class="top seller-identifier" href="#">Seller Number</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top seller-name" href="#">Seller Name</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top id-number" href="#">ID Number</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top company-name" href="#">Company Name</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top seller-email" href="#">Email</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="clear-search" href="#">Clear Search</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The only relevant CSS class is the `br` element which gives a margin to elements when they do wrap to the next line:

```
  br {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px 0;
    line-height: 15px;
    content: " ";
  }
```

Any idea on how to get that search box not to wrap to the second line and instead fill the space on the top right?

Comment: don't use `form-control` class it will not expand to the full width

Comment: If I remove form control from the input field, the QR button is still on the left, the search button still on the far right and the text field becomes a normal text field hanging in mid air.

Comment: it will take the width of its parent container ! Why don't you add a parent `row` and control its width using `col-xx-xx` ?

Comment: if you want your search-box to be in top-right than just add `pull-right` class in your span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap elements inside `.visible-lg-inline` into a `form` with class `navbar-form` and set `display:inline` to the `form` and a div with class `form-group` as below:

```
<span class="visible-lg-inline">
  <form class="navbar-form" style="display: inline;"> <!--Wrap it with form-->
          <div class="form-group"> <!--div with form-group class-->
            <div class="input-group br">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary qr-code">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-qrcode"></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
                <input class="form-control search top" type="search" name="search" placeholder="Search">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary search top dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            Search
                            <span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                            <li><a class="top seller-identifier" href="#">Seller Number</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top seller-name" href="#">Seller Name</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top id-number" href="#">ID Number</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top company-name" href="#">Company Name</a></li>
                            <li><a class="top seller-email" href="#">Email</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a class="clear-search" href="#">Clear Search</a></li>
                        </ul>

                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</span>
```

**[Fullscreen DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1cuyLjj5/1/embedded/result/)**

Comment: Using form seems hackish, but I guess it works. I've managed to get it working using a `btn-group` then adding an 'input-group' inside the `btn-group`, classing buttons before and after the search box with `input-group-btn` and adding a max-width to the whole search element button group.